# Does my SaaS provider use the same Docker images that they use for other users?

Tags: docker, virtualization, saas

When SaaS providers deploy a service by running it from a Docker container, do they use the same container image for multiple users?

For example, if two users require MySQL, will the provider run two containers from the same MySQL image, or will they use the customized images?

What tradeoffs does the decision involve?

Answer (score 0):

It depends but for the example you have asked, most probably they would use same image with different runtime configuration. This type of stuff(deploying a DB on demand etc) is usually automated, so it is rare that someone would be building a new image customised for a particular user.